# iTunes Store operation failed. WatchKit not supported

Tags: watchkit, itunes-store, apple-watch

I'm using Xcode 6.2.

Anybody able to upload Apple Watch apps to iTunes yet?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't submit apps with a WatchKit extension yet.  See the bottom of https://developer.apple.com/watchkit/.  It still says

> Please Note: Apps built with Xcode 6.2 and iOS 8.2 SDK may be
>   submitted to the App Store. However, WatchKit extensions are not
>   accepted at this time.

Comment: Thank you.  They are sending mixed messages by allowing showing the documentation in iTunes Connect describing how to upload your WatchKit apps.

Comment: Yeah I saw that and thought I would be able to upload my WatchKit app.  Also, ITC still doesn't have the fields for the watch app yet.

Comment: what makes it confusing is that it says once the binary with WatchKit is uploaded to the ITC the fields become available: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/Properties.html

http://i.imgur.com/nKa7bIl.png

Comment: Yes that is confusing!  I follow a lot of devs doing watch development and as best a I know, none of them have been able to submit yet.

Comment: I just noticed that Twitter released an Apple Watch update.  Are they giving bigger companies first go at pushing their Apple Watch apps?

http://i.imgur.com/nfaZ5Ah.png

Comment: Yes, there are some small companies as well.  See Dave Viewer's first article https://iosdevweekly.com.

Comment: Apple is now accepting WatchKit apps!

https://developer.apple.com/app-store/watch/